# Usage of "anymore"

Tags: grammar

Have I used ***anymore*** correctly in the following sentences?

1- I have no expectations of you anymore.

2- I don't have any expectations of you anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentences are correct, note the adverbial usage of ***[any more vs anymore](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/any-more-or-anymore)*** in BrE vs AmE:

> Any more is also an adverb and has the meaning of ‘no longer’ or ‘in the past but not now.’ ***In this meaning, we use it in end position***:
>
> - *We don’t go to Cornwall on holiday any more. (We used to go in the past but not now.)*
> - *The cost of electricity is not cheap any more.*

Note  that:

> ***Especially in American English, any more, as an adverb, can be written as one word, anymore:***
>
> - *He doesn’t cycle anymore*.

(Cambridge Dictionary)