# This song has been very popular, but now

Tags: grammar

A song was very popular between 2012 and 2014, but it has now lost its popularity.

Can these following sentences express the idea above?

> This song has been very popular, but it's not now.

> This song used to be very popular, but now it isn't.

Comment: but it isn't any more / https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/154705/2818

Answer (score 1):

With dates the OP should use the PAST SIMPLE, the action is confined to a specific point in the  past and cannot be repeated.

> 1. That song **was** very popular back **in 2012** but it soon **lost** its popularity.

If we say something *has been popular*, we suggest that the situation could change either in the present or in the future.

> Bell-bottom jeans **have seen** more than one revival since they became a fashion icon in the 1970s.

The OP's second sentence is grammatically fine.

> 2. This song **used to** be very popular, but now it isn't.